# syntax error(missing operator) in query

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I am working on microsoft access.I have three table for a library system.

> books(id,title,page,genre)
>
> authors(id,name)
>
> book_author(id,book_id,author_id)

books and book_author has 1 to many relationship

authors and book_authors has 1 to many relationship

to get the name of the author of a certain book i made the following query

```
SELECT authors.name  FROM  authors   WHERE books.id=1 ON books.id=book_author.book_id
```

But i am getting the following error .i don't know how to fix that.Please help

> syntax error(missing operator) in query

Comment: you're referring to `books` but it's not in your `from` also, you have an `on` without a `join`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT authors.name  
FROM  authors   
left join book_author on author.id = book_author.author_id
left join books on books.id = book_author.book_id
WHERE books.id=1;
```

Comment: i tried it and gives me the error   syntax error(missing operator) in query

Comment: what if you just do the first join to book_author and as a where statement just say book_author.book_id=1;

Comment: can you be a little more specific

Comment: SELECT authors.name  
FROM  authors   
left join book_author on author.id = book_author.author_id
where book_author.book_id=1;

Comment: i am getting the same error stated in the first comment

Answer (score 0):

```
Select authors.name, books.title
from books inner join book_author
on books.id = book_author.book_id
inner join authors
on book_author.author_id = authors.id
```

Get the name of the author of a certain book.
If you want to show the autor only, add a where condition.